# Salesforce Community suddenly not accessible

Tags: community, static-resources

Sometime today my Salesforce Community stopped being available to guest users.  For example, a guest user cannot access public static resources.  None of the fonts, etc. are accessible.  I am in desperate need of help.  Thoughts?

Comment: Same here - it's impacting all of our orgs.

Comment: Brad - what instance are you on?  I am not seeing an indication that this is impacting other organizations.  Do you see somewhere that Salesforce is working on this?

Comment: Also receiving outage reports, though I can't say what pod we are on. Seems like [Trust Status](https://status.salesforce.com/products/Community_Cloud/instances) is a bit lacking here...

Comment: Probably connected: https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/354

Comment: Another: https://status.salesforce.com/incidents/4777

Answer (score 3):

This is not yet on [Trust](https://trust.salesforce.com/en/) it seems. But there is a Communities outage and is affecting a wider audience and is mentioned on the [Help Site](https://help.salesforce.com/home)

[image]

[I should mention that I got this information internally within my team]

Comment: I wish I could trust trust.salesforce.com

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be global.

This error message is hidden in the dom with just a white page appearing.

"This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Assertion Failed!: Failed to find definition for dependency: force/customPerms : undefined
Failing descriptor: {markup://force:salesforceScopedModuleResolver}"

here's a google search that appears to show a bunch of lightning communities also affected.

https://www.google.com/search?q=This+page+has+an+error.+You+might+just+need+to+refresh+it.+Assertion+Failed!%3A+Failed+to+find+definition+for+dependency%3A+force%2FcustomPerms+%3A+undefined+Failing+descriptor%3A+%7Bmarkup%3A%2F%2Fforce%3AsalesforceScopedModuleResolver%7D&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS803US803&oq=This+page+has+an+error.+You+might+just+need+to+refresh+it.+Assertion+Failed!%3A+Failed+to+find+definition+for+dependency%3A+force%2FcustomPerms+%3A+undefined+Failing+descriptor%3A+%7Bmarkup%3A%2F%2Fforce%3AsalesforceScopedModuleResolver%7D&aqs=chrome..69i57.325j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8